# admin_post hook not called

Tags: hooks, actions

I have good experience in other CMS. but I'm very new in Wordpress.
My goal is to intercept POST values in some of the form of a pre-existent site.
Following documentation I've done the following steps:

- I had a look on the page source, finding that the form action:

> < form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  id='gform_4' 
>   action='/volunteer/'>

- in theme folder I modified function.php adding the code:

> add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_/volunteer/', 'send_contact_to_civicrm');
>
> add_action( 'admin_post_/volunteer/', 'send_contact_to_civicrm' );

- finally in the same .php file I added the function

> function send_contact_to_civicrm() { ... };

But my function is not executed. 
I also tried to modify the action name in 'admin_post_nopriv_volunteer' but with no result.

Where am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: The action on the form needs to be the the `admin url` and then you need a hidden form element with `name="action"` and `value="volunteer"`.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your form to include:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="volunteer">
    ...
</form>
```

and add an action to run your function:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_volunteer', 'send_contact_to_civicrm' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_volunteer', 'send_contact_to_civicrm' );

function send_contact_to_civicrm() {
   // stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that from the Dashboard, following the form->edit menu. But if I try to insert a hidden field there is no way (I didn't find it) to set "id" and "value" attributes. I also tried to set an HTML Content to "<input type="hidden" name="action" value="volontari">".  No result

Comment: It looks like your using Gravity forms - might be worth a look at the docs to see if you can hook into the form and add/update the necessary action(s).

Comment: Thanks "Gravity Forms" was the way. Using his hooks I solved

Answer (score 2):

Just checked the code in `admin-post.php`. Apparently when the user is authenticated the hook admin_post_ACTIONNAME is called.

BUT for an unauthorized request the hook `admin_post_nopriv_register_ACTIONAME` is called. So I thought everything worked fine on the website. Until an actual client of my practice informed me the register forms weren't operational at all.

AWESOME.

SO! I though I share this information for people who are trying to debug this damn hook.

Comment: So, you always have to register both?

Comment: I think so. One for authenticated users and one for guests. Depending on the needs of your form of course.

Comment: Oh man, I was wondering why my hook was not firing and then I read your answer. Thanks a bunch!